# Конфликт функций jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Извините за слишком простой вопрос, в jQuery почти не разбираюсь, а работу сделать надо.

Задача:
- Если выбрана радиокнопка - показывать скрытые изображение и текст, не скрывать пока не будет переключения на другую радиокнопку.
- По ховеру на текст радиокнопки - показывать только картинку.

При моем коде отрабатывает только вторая функция с ховером. Т.е. при наведении на радиокнопку картинка появляется, но при выборе - нет.

Как это исправить?

```js
<script>
    $('.img2, .img3, .img4, .img5, .img6, .img7').hide();
    $('#pic1').css('opacity','1');
    $('.text').hide();

    $(document).ready(function() {
    
   $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
       if($(this).attr('id') == 'item1') {
            $('#pic5, #text1').show();
       }

       else {
            $('.img5, #text1').hide();   
       }
   });
   
    $("#desc1").mouseenter(function(){
        $('#pic5').show();
    });
    $("#desc1").mouseleave(function(){
       $('#pic5').hide();
    });
    
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: отрабатывают то обе, но когда вы после клика убираете мышь, то картинка снова скрывается.

Comment: Не подскажете что нужно исправить, чтобы функции работали параллельно? При ховере картинка появляется-исчезает, при выборе появляется и остается?

Comment: А так в коде show и hide на картинку работают независимо. Сделай при наведении дополнительную проверку на состояние radio. Если нажата, то не скрывать при отведении, если не нажата, то скрывать. Вначале, лучше все, что выполняется JQuery запихнуть в функцию $(document).ready().
Ну и чтобы лучше понять проблемы выложите пример на каком-либо сервисе, наподобие jsfiddle.net или codepen.io. Уверен, что так вы получите совет или решение быстрее.